# Why do I see different result using files vs sudo nautilus?

Tags: 20.04

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 directly on dedicated hardware. This morning I noticed that if I simply start the file manager using files I see less on the left as opposed to using the terminal and issuing sudo nautilus?

Here is what I see when opening files. On the left is the view from files. On the right is the view from sudo nautilus:[Two different views of Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVnen.jpg) Why this difference other than the use of sudo? My account is set up as admin.

Comment: Never run `sudo nautilus`.

Comment: But I am trying to create two folders via bash and they are not visible otherwise.

Comment: still no reason to do `sudo nautilus` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When you run `nautilus` as a normal user, it shows the user's Home directory that is `/home/$USER`.

When you run it with `sudo` is shows the home directory of `root` user that is `/root`.

Never run `nautilus` with `sudo`. It creates temporary files owned by `root` that can cause some trouble in the future.

You can use terminal commands to do file operations that require `sudo`, or install Midnight Commander `mc` for that purpose that can be run with `sudo`.

If it is too difficult to use CLI, then at least run it this way:

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I suspected it had something to do with /root. So I used sudo-H nautilus and it appears the same as sudo nautilus. What does the -H do?

Comment: I think it is default now. It prevents creating files owned by root in a user directory.

Comment: Ahhh - that makes sense.